# How to access to the 'appdata' folder?

Tags: python

i got this code:

```
from pathlib import Path


home = Path.home()
print(home)
```

The output is `C:\Users\ItsBlackZ\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data`.

I need to access to the `AppData\Roaming` folder and not the `SPB_Data` folder, how do i "cd" to the previous folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parent` attribute.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) which returns the parent of the path.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>>  
>>> home = Path.home()  
>>> print(home.parent)
```

Comment: tysm!!! this worked for me.